# Conflict between .show() and .append() in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div with `id="poidiv"` whose `display` is `'none'` initially. Now I want to load it more than once with a loop (the max value of the loop is dynamic). I tried it with JQuery `.append().clone()`.

Here is the example code--

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $("#levelnext").click(function(){
        for(i=1; i<=level; i++){  
            $("#leveldiv").append($("#poidiv").clone().removeAttr("id"));
        }
    });
});
```

But because the `display` of `"poidiv"` was initially `'none'`, it does not appear with this piece of code. Now if I want to show it with `.show()` before the loop starts, the loop is not working in a good manner. What might be a good solution in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) in the chain, like this:

```
$("#leveldiv").append($("#poidiv").clone().removeAttr("id").show());
```

Comment: @zeb - do you have an example page? it should work, unless the children of what you're appending are also hidden...or `#leveldiv` is hidden  (or either has default styling to be hidden).

Comment: http://aiworker2.usask.ca/dbload/pp1.html ---- here you can view the source code..

Comment: @zeb - You need to move the `click` handler *outside* your `loopControll` function (which is binding it many times), just inside a `document.ready`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bBGZQ/ then just get rid of your `loopControll` function and the reference to it.  Here's a full working version so you can see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bBGZQ/1/

Comment: 1 thing Nick ... This piece of code is not working with IE ... any idea?

Comment: @zeb - It should given valid markup, are you sure your page is valid? http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: The 'levelnext' button is not working out. You can try it from IE- http://aiworker2.usask.ca/dbload/pp1.html